# How to perform Bader charge analysis in QUANTUM ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, charge-density

Suppose I have a test calculation, for two atoms in an unit cell. I have the charge density files in 1D and 3D, calculated using pseudopotential approach. How can I do the Bader analysis with QUANTUM ESPRESSO DFT?

Could you please explain each steps in easier way with necessary screenshots/codes?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but do you have any update now? Have you figured this out? Are you still actively needing the answer?

Comment: Thanks @NikeDattani. It would be great to hear some responses in this, if someone has experience in doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Considering that it took you more than 6 months to respond to my comment though, would it be fair for me to conclude that this is not an urgent or high-priority issue for you?